# File is not decoded properly

Tags: python

I have a file encoded in a strange pattern. For example,

**Char (1 byte) | Integer (4 bytes) | Double (8 bytes) | etc...**

So far, I wrote the code below, but I have not been able to figure out why still shows garbage in the screen. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
BRK_File = 'commands.BRK'
input = open(BRK_File, "rb")

rev = input.read(1)
filesize = input.read(4)
highpoint = input.read(8)
which = input.read(1)

print 'Revision: ', rev 
print 'File size: ', filesize
print 'High point: ', highpoint
print 'Which: ', which

while True
    opcode = input.read(1)
    print 'Opcode: ', opcode
    if opcode = 120:
         break
    elif
        #other opcodes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read()` returns a string, which you need to decode to get the binary data. You could use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#module-struct) module to do the decoding.

Something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
import struct
...
fmt = 'cid' # char, int, double
data = input.read(struct.calcsize(fmt))
rev, filesize, highpoint = struct.unpack(fmt, data)
```

You may have to deal with endianness issues, but `struct` makes that [pretty easy](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Comment: I believe the last field is a char:  `fmt = 'cidc'`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: This wasn't meant as a complete example. Just showing the idea...

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. Also, I am a newbie in python; I would greatly appreciate if you could further delve in his observation.

Comment: Also, I do not know in advance the type of each element. Later on, I will be cycling in a loop and checking for extra data. Is there a way to not hardcode the types (get rid off 'cid'?

Comment: @Peretz:  Define "in advance".  Surely you won't be guessing?

Comment: @Steven: Depending on the opcode, I will have to decode different sequences of memory sizes. Until the opcode end of file does not come in, I will continue in a loop. I am updating the code to reflect this.

Comment: Then make a dictionary mapping opcode to format characters (http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters).  `d = {'char':'c','int','i'}; data = input.read(struct.calcsize(d[opcode])); converted = struct.unpack(d[opcode]), data)`.  Or something like that.

Comment: @Peretz: Perhaps you mean "While" instead of "Until", or "does come in" instead of "does not come in"

Comment: @Steven: I am kind of new with python, by chance could you add the code to this answer so I can get a better idea on how to implement the dictionary mapping.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to show the contents of the file, as well as the "garbage" that it's outputting.

input.read() returns a string, so you have to convert what you're reading to the type that you want. I suggest looking into the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module.